# Wiring money out of Brazil, are there taxes?

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, international-transfer, brazil

I am helping a family member sell some property in Brazil, and transfer the money to his US bank account. I'm doing research on what we need to do to do the transfer safely and legally.

I found [some documentation](https://ttlc.intuit.com/questions/2930266-transfer-money-from-my-foreign-bank-account-to-us-bank-account) suggesting that the US doesn't tax international transfers to US bank accounts, which is great news, but I can't find any documentation on what Brazil's laws are.

Does the US really not tax transfers in?

And what taxes do I need to look at in Brazil?

Answer (score 0):

Most countries tax *income* in its various ways, but not *moving* money.

If this is a movement of already owned money, it is not tax-relevant. If it is a payment for services done, it is *income*, and it is the recipient's duty to pay taxes on it.

Note that transferring large amounts of money (10k+) between countries *can* trigger a review, which - worst case - results in questions where it came from. The point of that is solely to verify it was *legally earned* money (not drug money or such). There is nothing to worry about if the money was legally earned.

Comment: While it may be true that moving money is not tax relevant to most countries, Brazil does have a tradition of taxing money transfers. That tax does not exist anymore, but drafts to reinstate it appear from time to time. Also, currency exchange is taxed in Brazil.